Problem with data given for transformer design
I'm using STelectronics design tool for making a SMPS, you can check this link to design yours STelectronics Designer.
The problem is that with the given data of the transformer is not clear for me, I'm not acquainted with the english vocabulary in electronics, and I can't extract the relevant data.
I let you my design specs, so you can see it yourself:
Input minimum voltage: 190V
Input maximum voltage: 250V
Input Frequency: 50Hz
Output Voltage: 15V
Output current: 10A
Also I let you the designs that this specs give me:


What does it mean with "Paralleled", with TCA2 DIW, Litz 105? What data should I give to the transformer manufacturer for making this transformer?
EDIT
I let you the circuit that is being used with the transformer:


Pretty much what it says, to use paralleled wires for that winding. It's not uncommon in SMPS transformers if you have high current and frequency and want to avoid the cost of Litz wire to use several in parallel instead. It can also boil down to having an even number of turns to fill out one layer. You will have more options here by allowing parallel wires but the downside is that your helix angle (not sure if there is a better name for it, winding angle?) will go up by using paralleled wires so each start and end of a layer will have a bit more waste.
Talk to your transformer manufacturer and check with them, some have strong preference for some wire types over others and online generators like these (powerelab comes to mind too) have little consideration of availability and supply chain.

But for example in secondary winding, It will be 7 turns of 3 paralleled Litz 105 wire? My Input Voltage is around 220VAC. What input value should I give to the manufacturer? Because in these images, the input will be around 150V ( Np/Ns * Secondary Voltage ).

@samuelmattio Oh, 50 Hz, not 50 kHz? It's not an SMPS?

Input signal of the circuit has 50hz, not of the transformer. The transformer around 100Khz

You need to use 100 kHz for your calculations. I assume you have input PFC or at least diode bridge+capacitor? If the latter, you need to calculate both for minimum and maximum DC link voltage.

I uploaded the circuit so you have a better understanding on what I'm trying to do. Anyway, I still don't understand the copper section spec. For example, auxiliary: "Single 0.102mm" and then downwards "0.008 > 0.006". Wich one is the section of the auxiliary? I suppose that is 0.008mm section, because 0.102mm is large for what the circuit requires, but what is trying to say with "single 0.102mm"?

EER49 for 150 W. Ouch. Have you considered a different topology than flyback given your load? It’s not impossible by any means, but if you intend to mass produce these in high quantities, there is cost to be saved. Your schematic lacks designators so I can’t refer to it directly. The aux would be the lower one on the primary side. <0.1 mm^2 becomes hard to wind. Again, check with your transformer manufacturer.

What topology you recommend for this load? If i stick with this one, what core do you recommend?  I was also looking for EE55, is this more accurate?

Forward or possibly half-bridge. Calculate the total BOM cost for your flyback today with the two others. CCM flyback at 150 W isn’t unheard of.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
